# Get Max "laps" but with minimum "time" from 3 results as join

Tags: mysql

I'm at a loss and hoping for some help.  I've searched SOF, google and tried as many things as I can think but can't get anything even close to what I'm after (so far away there is no point in posting my attempts).

**results table**

```
result_id
wcics_live_id
class_id
main
round_num
```

**results_drivers table**

```
rd_id
result_id
user_id
race_time   (ex. 5:06.231, this is minutes:seconds)
laps        (ex. 25)
```

For each class_id a driver will have 3 entries in the results_drivers table, for example:

```
Luke Pittman      25 laps     5:06.231
Luke Pittman      24 laps     5:00.691
Luke Pittman      25 laps     5:05.914
```

Additionally, each class will have multiple drivers - could be as many as 40 or 50.

I need to be able to gather a list of all the drivers, in order of the fastest time (highest laps with lowest race_time), but only returning one result for each driver.  For example:

```
Faster Guy        26 laps     5:11.134
Luke Pittman      25 laps     5:05.914
Joe Doe           25 laps     5:06.014
Other Guy         24 laps     5:00.141
... and so on
```

Normally I would do a group by with a max value (or something similar) on a column, but I have no idea how to make that happen with 2 separate columns.

Comment: See [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: I literally don't know how to start - that's the issue.  The response posted below confuses the hell outta me.  lol

Comment: Hence the advice above.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do a query with `MAX(laps) ... GROUP BY user_id`, and then reference that as an inline view in another query, to get the minimum race_time

Something like this:

```
SELECT ft.user_id
     , ft.laps
     , MIN(ft.race_time) AS race_time
  FROM ( -- maximum laps 
         SELECT dr.user_id
              , MAX(dr.laps) AS max_laps
           FROM driver_results dr
          GROUP BY dr.user_id
       ) ml
  JOIN driver_results ft
    ON ft.user_id = ml.user_id
   AND ft.laps    = ml.laps
 GROUP
    BY ft.user_id
     , ft.laps
 ORDER
    BY laps ASC
     , race_time DESC
```

(I'm assuming here that the `laps` and `race_time` columns are canonical, such that ORDER BY and MIN/MAX will work to get the highest number of laps and fastest time.  If these are stored as strings, then it won't necessarily work right. i.e. if comparing strings: '10:23.456' will be less than '8:15.555'.